# How to grep including single quote in a file

Tags: shell, grep, quoting

I have this line from `file.php`:

```
'user' => '',
```

What would be the appropriate command using grep to query the exact line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use double quotes to enclose your pattern:

```
grep "'user' => ''," your_file
```

I would also make use of some metacharacters to ensure the lookup is robust to the different spacing styles used by people:

```
grep "'user'\s*=>\s*''\s*," your_file
```

To add different keywords to your search, you need extended regular expressions. Supply the `-E` switch to `grep`:

```
grep -E "'(user|group|foo)'\s*=>\s*''\s*," your_file
```

The above will print lines matching `'user' => '',` or `'group' => '',` or `'foo' => '',` (with different spacing variations). Modify as needed.

Comment: Great. How about to search/query another keyword let say 'group' => '';

Comment: @JamesW. Answer updated.