# AWK special character

Tags: awk, ksh

If i want to awk the below pattern in a file

```
Mobilenumber '91_987986787688899' was successful
```

I used the below code

```
awk '/Mobilenumber '91_987986787688899' was successful/ {print $0}' Log Filename
```

Though the log file has that sentence its not rendering any result.

I spent a while on this but was not successful... Please help

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `grep`:

```
grep "91_987986787688899.*successful" file
```

Unless your file has a very strange format, you could also probably just do this:

```
awk '/91_987986787688899.*successful/' file
```

There is no need for `print $0`, it is implied.

Answer (score 2):

Simply [enclose your pattern in double quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90462/how-to-grep-including-single-quote-in-a-file/90463#90463). In your case though, you'll want to escape `$` to avoid variable interpolation by the shell:

```
awk "/Mobilenumer '91_987986787688899' was successful/ {print \$0}" your_file
```

You can also use `sed` whose default action is to print its pattern space:

```
sed "/Mobilenumer '91_987986787688899' was successful/" your_file
```